# Apply function to each row in pandas with a condition : Truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3],
                   'img': ['x',0,'x']
                 })

def details(id):

    return 2

df['new_col'] = df['img'].apply(lambda x: details(x['id']) if x == 0 else x, axis=1)
```

I'd like to apply the function only to rows, where cell value == 0. When I run the above line, I get this error:

```
   ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1327 
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1329         raise ValueError(
   1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: This code can't produce this error. You're using Series apply here not DataFrame apply meaning `x` is an int. You would be either getting `<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'` or `'int' object is not subscriptable`. Will you fix your MRE to something that can reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3],
                   'img': ['x',0,'x']
                 })

def details(id):
    return 2

df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: details(row['id']) if row['img'] == 0 else row['img'], axis=1)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iloc'`

Comment: No, I didn't. Sample code posted here is slightly different, let me modify.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the mre is not reproducible.

Here's how I got it to work, though:

```
# Read Pandas DataFrame 

df['img'] = df.apply(lambda x: details(x['id']) if type(x['img']) == int else x['img'], axis=1)
```